# Excel/VBA to Application

Tags: application-design, engineering, applications, excel, vba

In an engineering company, there are many engineers that edit in Excel/VBA Spreadsheets to perform some engineering calculations.They all do more or less similar things: calculate, manage engineering stability, buildings, infrastructure etc.. They perform calculations based on data and formulas. Or draw a picture of uncommon case based on the given data in the sheet.

Surely, Excel Spreadsheets is easy to write, copy-paste, print. But they are unsafe and hard to maintain or centralize.

Some of that "home-grown" applications became mature, and the head office should decide to transform them into real application(s), to be able to protect and better manage them.

Another problem is often the authors of such Excel files are the only people that understands what is happening behind the scenes... and if the application became popular inside a company, this can create problems if that person moves from the company in a way or another... a popular corporate application can't be maintained by one single person.

So the problem is, how can I better transform these kind of applications? Here are some options:

- transform one by one, one sheet to one application, or
- group in one all together
- as a desktop or
- a web-application...

Now, there may be a way to let the authors for this Excel data to be allowed to contribute (without the need to learn additional programming language).

Does anyone face similar problems, maybe reflected by the architecture of the transformation of Excel/VBA "application" to real "applications"...

Comment: My limited experience is that your application won't do something they want, so they'll write a new Excel spreadsheet to do it...

Comment: Also your reasons to *not* use Excel spreadsheets are not as important as you think they are.

Comment: @user253751 like security reasons? there is not possible nor to protect an excel sheet from modifications, nor from unauthorized distribution. also the maintainability, version control etc...

Answer (score 4):

You tackle this problem like you would tackle any other software engineering problem: by gathering requirements, designing the software, writing it, testing it, and so forth.  Having spreadsheets that already do this just means that some of the requirements gathering has already been done for you.

The manner in which you organize the software is where the design process comes in.  Collectively, this is known as the application's architecture.  As you've pointed out, there are various ways to organize software, but unless your spreadsheets demarcate different departments in the company (and even if they do), it's most likely going to be a single application.  It really just depends on what the size and scope of the project is.

I wouldn't rely on the folks who created the spreadsheets to help you *write* the software.  If they were software engineers, they would have already transformed the spreadsheets into an application.  Use them as your stakeholders/business analysts.

Comment: the idea of contribution of the excel sheets creators was not about participation to the portal building or architecture, but rather to the portal "extensions", if they have new ideas of "sheets", to implement them as "plug-ins" to the existing portal, or something in this genre

Comment: Making software modular and extensible is almost always a good thing.

Answer (score 4):

I would question the very premise of the question that Excel/VBA is "unsafe", that it is a "home" application, or that it is hard to maintain when applied to appropriate problems.

Excel and VBA is widely used by professionals in the largest corporations, and (due to the ubiquity of Excel and its built-in VBA editor) it is amongst some of the quickest and easiest code to produce and maintain for one-trick-pony type calculators, utilities, or reports.

One of Excel's main advantages is its accessibility to people whose main role is not programming, but whose role has some routine or repetitive data processing element which can be automated, or indeed some graphical rendering element you also mention.

So on conversion to a "proper" application, which is often slower, more bloated, with a UI that is perhaps more badly done, and actually far harder for the end-user to maintain or have changed, one may ask why you would wish to do it?

Has the complexity grown to a point where only experienced analysts and developers can be expected to handle the code at all, rather than supporting the individual or department within the terms of existing practices using Excel?

Are there any other specific problems emerging, rather than a vague sense that existing practice is unsafe?

If you do decide to convert, realise that reproducing the full UI functionality of Excel in a desktop application will be difficult, and to do so via a web page more difficult again.

And if there are still some Excel tools used, then now your staff have two places to look for the relevant tool rather than one, using two user interface languages, and based on two different coding platforms.

Comment: I upvoted this. Excel/VBA is not "unsafe" or "hard to maintain" per se. But to be fair, Excel sheets created by *"people whose main role is not programming"* have a certain risk to become hard to maintain (not because of Excel, but because of people who are not trained in writiing maintainable software).

Comment: @DocBrown, agreed, I've encountered spaghetti code in Excel many a time. In such cases, a proportionate solution might be to share good practices with the creator, to refactor to a better standard, or to formalise and document any muddled analysis. Or it might just be to verify that there is a fallback (such as a paper calculation or a written procedure) if their code fails, and let them get on with doing their best.

Comment: Excel/VBA is unsafe, the password can be easily broken, at least several years ago I found programs/scripts that break such passwords, so I were able to access the VBA code or unprotect sheets of which passwords were forgotten

Comment: And after all, Excel Spreadsheets simply can be copied to an USB key and used without limitations by third persons that could give or even sell such sheets to concurrence...

Comment: @Serge, the whole point is that the staff who use them have access to the code, especially if they wrote the code! Perhaps the staff can walk out with the sheet, but they can just as easily walk out with the training materials, the paper procedures, or with their own embodied expertise. (1/2)

Comment: I think firms often over-estimate the value of code written in lightweight ways by non-IT staff such as with Excel, as against the swingeing costs of banning automation tools or of having everything done "properly" by a central IT department, and against all the other ways in which supposed trade secrets can already leak out of the firm. When firms become obsessed with controlling the information necessary for the execution of people's jobs, they more often seem to forget their own trade secrets and fail to reproduce their expertise internally. (2/2)

Comment: @Serge: such Excel sheets are not different from that compared to other "non-programmatic" documents, so they require the same forms of protection. This is usually an NDA in the working contracts of the staff. This is for organisational environments where that kind of confidentiality is sufficient. In organisations with higher security requirements, staff must be forbidden to send external emails with attachments, or to carry any physical storage media like USB sticks out of the bureaus.

Comment: @DocBrown "staff must be forbidden" does not mean the "staff will not do it". Another problem is often the authors of such Excel files are the only people that understands what is happening behind the scenes... and if the application became popular inside a company, this can create problems if that person moves from the company in a way or another... a popular corporate application can't be maintained by one single person.

Comment: @Serge: code which is understood by one and only person can always lead to problems when the author leaves the company, this has nothing to do with Excel.

Comment: it has, Excel sheets code is not versionable, and can't be edited by a group of people, or shared in tools like GitHub by eg

Comment: @Serge: tell me something I don't know. I am not saying Excel should be abused as a replacement for proper application development where  proper application development is required. I am just telling you Steve's answer is 100% on spot - one should not convert any Excel based spreadsheet with some VBA code overhastily for ideological reasons into something which does not really fit to the requirements of the business any more. This is a step which has a cost, and the cost must be worth it, not just from the IT side, but also from the business side.

Comment: @Serge, the thing to understand is that the process and knowledge of key staff members is also not versionable or editable by a group of people (except by directly working with the relevant staff member), and almost nobody in a business will even know what GitHub is. If an Excel sheet is popular, creating and maintaining it may already be consuming a significant percentage of the creator's working time, not just on the programming side (which may be sloppy and done with very little overhead), but on the analysis side (which will tend to be in their heads and also with little overhead). (1/2)

Comment: If you do what they're doing through a formal method, and add in all the overheads, you might end up adding an FTE to the IT department, purely to look after what that one Excel sheet currently does, and to ensure that change requests are executed *within the day they are requested*, not next year or never. Does the IT budget stretch that far? Some backbone applications justify millions in development and maintenance costs by dedicated staff. But not everything does. (2/2)

Comment: @Steve, surely, if in a corporation there are tens, or even hundreds of excel "home made" locally useful sheets, some one, the most popular and most used would be transformed to apps... But the challenge is to let people participate to the ideas and formulas, but keep them away from programming stuff, that would be the change of the  head corp developers...

Comment: @Serge, there's two very different ideas being expressed there. One is that you take the most popular, proven-useful local sheets and transform them into functionality provided and overseen by central IT. The other is that you "keep away from programming stuff" everyone but "head corp developers". Those are not equivalent statements.

Comment: @Steve is like Microsoft opened the .NET Core to anyone, but they however have the control of the quality of the product assured by head corp devs. Here, a sheet trending to grow and be bigger and bigger, like a dinosaur, should be controlled by the corporation, if not, the corp can't assure the quality and standard's compliance the Corporation is responsible of...

Comment: @Serge, there are many kinds of quality. If you have 100 sheets which are growing like dinosaurs, have you wondered about the complexity of the *manual* processes, and what are you going to do to ensure the corporation controls those? And if you have a quality assurance process for your own code, what defects is it designed to catch?

Comment: I have 100 sheets, but I need to "Applicate" only, say, five dinosaurs.

Comment: @Serge, if you are sure you need to, then only you can judge.

Comment: @Steve I can't let it as is, because I receive it from unknown author and I need to maintain it... and after some time to pass no another people to maintain it... what would you do in that case? Tens of pages updating one another without any specs nor description or code comments, used about a thousand time in a day by different people around the globe and asking everyone for updates here and there...

Comment: @Serge, having inherited a similar Excel sheet myself in the past, after the author had left, and being tasked with improving its accuracy, my approach was to clarify the desired calculation on paper first, which eventually took months. If the whole sheet is muddled, your users will likely appreciate it being rationalised and brought back into logical order.

Comment: Your task was to improve the accuracy, and in order to change it, you should first spend months to understand it. Then if you modify it there's any garantee you didn't broke the formula elsewhere. There's any way to unit test it to guarantee the stability. There's hard to roll back and understand what version of sheet produced what output in a given place and time... In a word, it's a maintenance hell... And imagine after months you should pass the maintenance to someone else...

Comment: Actually, I am talking about desktop Excel. There are different Excel languages, and formulas are different for each of them. Now, there are also office 365 there you could have the simulation of the versioning...

Comment: @Serge, in this case of mine, the problem was a lack of clear ontology for the calculation. There were all sorts of magic constants and unnamed lookup tables and unexpected dependencies, and nobody could be clear how they were derived or what their exact role was in the calculation. The users were expected to use professional judgment to override certain elements, but there was a lack of any clear guidance like "if you override this, then you also need to review these dependent values". (1/2)

Comment: As I say, the answer was having a paper calculation as the definitive reference, with a written procedure, various supporting documents and tables, and a working sheet that declared and stored every intermediate value generated by the procedure. When on paper, people are less inclined to tolerate things like "lookup a value in unnamed table X", "multiply by magic value 42", without asking questions about what the hell it means! Automating a well-structured paper calculation is also trivial, and the code then contains no secrets which aren't present in the paper version. (2/2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117760/discussion-between-serge-and-steve).